# warning: templates not found /share/git-core/templates | fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: windows, git, curl, github, git-clone

I'm getting the following messages while trying to clone a github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
Cloning into 'test'...
warning: templates not found /share/git-core/templates
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

- windows 8.1
- git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0
- in my PATH: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
- http://windows.github.com/ is also installed on my system (cloning with it is working)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. 
It was [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) (the full version which include msysgit) which somehow was in conflict with my already installed msysgit.
So removing cmder of my computer fixed the problem. If you are using the "mini" version it should work though.
If interested, I opened an issue https://github.com/bliker/cmder/issues/144